# finding a closed formula to an expression and prove it by induction

Tags: calculus

Let  > 0, find a closed formula (no sigmas) for

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\log_a n} a^i $$

i found this formula:
$$ \frac{a(n-1)}{a-1}$$
but i have trouble proving by induction
i dont really understand what is the base case, the hypothesis and the step
please help, thanks

Comment: Use formula for sum of first k terms of geometric progression where k=log_a(n)

Comment: What is exactly the upper summation limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you provided is accurate only when $log_a{n}$ is an integer. So, to solve it by induction, you will need to prove that if the formula is true for $n$, it must also be true for $an$. For base case just using $n=1$ works.

Proof of Inductive Step : 
$$\displaystyle\sum^{log_a{n}}_{i=1}a^i = \dfrac{a(n-1)}{n-1} \Rightarrow \sum^{log_a{n}}_{i=1}a^i + a^{log_a{an}}= \dfrac{a(n-1)}{n-1} + an = 
\dfrac{a(n-1)+a^2n - an}{n-1} = \dfrac{a(an-1)}{n-1} = \sum^{log_a{n}+1}_{i=1}a^i$$

Comment: you really helped me, thank you!